# Avoid Postback when calling code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to do some input validation on an ASP form and if the validation fails it's not supposed to try and submit the form but simply show a modal window (bootstrap) with the error and then let the user fix the error/fill in the blanks they forgot.

But whenever I press my HTML button (or ASP button I've tried both) it shows the modal window and does a postback right after. I can see that this happens because I have to upload fields that lose their file references and I have a dynamically created dropdown which also resets.

I would like to find a way to get around this but after looking at several SO answers I havne't found a solution.

Using the popular `return false;` solution makes the submit button stop working all together.

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <script>
        function activityAdd() {
            __doPostBack('Activity_Add', 'postback');
        };
    </script>
    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" Style="font-size: 20px;" runat="server" OnClientClick="activityAdd();" Text="Submit"/>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" runat="server" href="~/Index" style="font-size: 20px;">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

C# Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "CreateDepartmentDropdown", "$(document).ready(function(){CreateDepartmentDropdown(" + GetDepartmentDropdownList() + ");});", true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "RegisterDatepickers", "$(document).ready(function(){RegisterDatepickers();});", true);
    //Activity_Add.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");
    //Activity_Add.Click += Activity_Submit_Click;
    if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "postback")
    {
        SubmitActivity();
    }
}
```

And the Submit Method:

```
public bool SubmitActivity()
{
    bool InputValidated = true;
    List<String> ErrorMessages = new List<String>();

    int fye = Int32.Parse(fye_dropdown.Value);
    String activityName = activity_name_field.Value;
    String[] ax_accounts = (ax_account_numbers_field.Value.Contains(',') ? ax_account_numbers_field.Value.Split(',') : new String[1] { ax_account_numbers_field.Value });

    if (activityName.Length == 0)
    {
        InputValidated = false;
        ErrorMessages.Add("The Activity Name is not filled.");
    }
    String activity_responsible = responsible_field.Value;
    int department;

    if (department_dropdown_selected_value.Value.Length == 0)
    {
        department = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        department = Int32.Parse(department_dropdown_selected_value.Value);
    }

    DateTime start;
    DateTime end;

    // Since the dates are formatted for Americans we will rearrange day and month in code.
    // Otherwise the JavaScript that checks the two Calendars break and we can't parse a DateTime object.
    try
    {
        String[] date = datepicker_start.Value.Split('/');
        String parseString = date[1] + "/" + date[0] + "/" + date[2] + " 00:00:00 AM";
        start = DateTime.Parse(parseString);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        InputValidated = false;
        ErrorMessages.Add("The Start Date was not formatted right. Please only click in the box and choose a date from the calendar.");
    }

    try
    {
        String[] date = datepicker_start.Value.Split('/');
        String parseString = date[1] + "/" + date[0] + "/" + date[2] + " 00:00:00 AM";
        end = DateTime.Parse(parseString);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        InputValidated = false;
        ErrorMessages.Add("The End Date was not formatted right. Please only click in the box and choose a date from the calendar.");
    }

    if (ax_accounts[0].Length == 0)
    {
        InputValidated = false;
        ErrorMessages.Add("You need to add at least one AX Account for the Activity.");
    }

    if (!description_upload.HasFile)
    {
        InputValidated = false;
        ErrorMessages.Add("Please choose a file to upload for the Detailed Description of the Activity");
    }

    if (!estimation_upload.HasFile)
    {
        InputValidated = false;
        ErrorMessages.Add("Please choose a file to upload for the Estimation of the Activity.");
    }

    if (InputValidated == false)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("An Error happened while submitting the activity. Please see below for details.");
        sb.Append("<br>");
        foreach (String msg in ErrorMessages)
        {
            sb.Append("- ").Append(msg).Append("<br>");
        }
        String jsExec = Util.ModalAlert(sb.ToString(), "#error_modal", ".modal-body");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "error_modal_show", jsExec, false);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] descriptionBytes = description_upload.FileBytes;
        String descriptionFileName = description_upload.FileName;

        byte[] estimationBytes = estimation_upload.FileBytes;
        String estimationFileName = estimation_upload.FileName;

        String msg = Util.Alert("Success");
        Response.Write(msg);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work as expected either. All the fields mentioned earlier still reset. It's infuriating me to no end because it's going to be a frustrating experience for the user. Any idea on how to approach this problem?

Comment: What happens when you use 'return false;'? onclick="addActivity();return false;" will execute your onclick event without postback?

Comment: `<asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-success" Style="font-size: 20px;" runat="server" OnClientClick="activityAdd(); return false;" Text="Submit"/>` this line executes but still resets all my fields even though it's supposed to just show the modal window and nothing else.

Comment: I was referring to a conventional HTML button. Perhaps move return false inside the called function?

Comment: I tried that before and that made the button not work at all.

Comment: I'm confused by that! See https://jsfiddle.net/LmL1t008/1/ - this works?

Comment: Still no dice. It keeps resetting the aforementioned fields.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating this?

Comment: That's kind of hard since this is ASP and I need to call code behind.